Get the value of the second non-empty cell in a row



0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L




1
Product

2023-Saels
2023-Margin

2024-Saels
2024-Margin

2025-Sales
2025-Margin

Result


2
Product A

500
30%

150
40%

160
5%

30%


3
Product B

200
10%

900
60%

750
8%

10%


4
Product C

300
19%

400
10%

400
60%

19%


5
Product D




700
50%

930
25%

50%


6
Product E







800
15%

15%


7
Product F







430
32%

32%


8
Product G







360
45%

45%




In Column L I want to display for each product the very first margin per product which is the second non-empty cell in each row. 
So far I have been able to develop this formula:
=XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(C2:J2),C2:J2)

It correctly gives me the very first sales which is the first non-empty cell in each row. 
How do I need to modify it to display the second non-empty cell in each row? 

This should solve your problem, you are in right path
=XLOOKUP(1,ISNUMBER(C2:J2)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH("margin",$C$1:$J$1)),C2:J2)

Likely multiple options. Here's one using BYROW, FILTER, and INDEX:
=BYROW(C2:J8,LAMBDA(x, INDEX(FILTER(x,ISNUMBER(x)),,2)))



Too Late... I had come up with =IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(B2:J2, ISNUMBER(B2:J2)), 2), "No second value") But yours is better :)

mmh, when I use your formula it returns #VALUE!. Not sure if it is related with my Excel. I am using Office365. I also translated the formula to the German format. I can see in the screenshot it works all on your side.

Odd. I can't replicate the #VALUE! error, but can create a #REF! or #CALC! error...

I think the issue is the BYROW function. I have the same issue with the BYCOL function. When I use the english name it is not recognized and I am getting #NAME? error. I searched for a German translation but it seems there is no translation for it.

NACHZEILE according to reddit

@Michi use this website, will get all the functions from English to German translated. https://excelhero.de/excel-funktionen/

Here is alternative method using BYROW() + CHOOSECOLS() + TOCOL() :


=BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(C2:J8,2,5,8),LAMBDA(α,@TOCOL(α/(α<>""),2,1)))



With old functions. In cell F1 and drag down. If no second value exists a #REF error is returned.
=INDEX(A1:D1,SMALL(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A1:D1)),COLUMN(A1:D1)-COLUMN(A1)+1,1E+200),2))


Pls. according to SO rules , not answer in comments, rather in another answer.  Either post it or comment it in the question if you are not sure in something.

@Manoj Your formula gives a false result if there is a gap between the first and second number.

Formula in cell
T3 =INDEX(J3:S3,,1+MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(J3:S3),0))
and cell
F1 =INDEX(A1:D1,,1+MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(A1:D1),0))
Here is the result, It will give error only when there is no second number.

